# Get AdSense Ads to Reload on Route Change in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ads, adsense

We've implemented Google AdSense on our Next.JS website, but we'd like to have ads reload whenever the route changes.

Here is what I tried:

```
const AdBlock = props => {
  const { userLoaded, currentUserIsSilverPlus } = useAuth()

  useEffect(() => {
    window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []
    window.adsbygoogle.push({})
  }, [])

  const reloadAds = () => {
    const { googletag } = window
    if (googletag) {
      googletag.cmd.push(function () {
        googletag.pubads().refresh()
      })
    }
  }

  Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", reloadAds)

  if (userLoaded && !currentUserIsSilverPlus) {
    return (
      <ins
        className="adsbygoogle adbanner-customize"
        style={{ display: "block" }}
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-1702181491157560"
        data-ad-slot={props.slot}
        data-ad-format={props.format}
        data-full-width-responsive={props.responsive}
      />
    )
  }
  return ""
}

export default AdBlock
```

The ads load, however, they never appear to refresh. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue too, the ad unit displays on first page load, then on Next.js route change the ad unit doesn't display ads anymore unless the page was refreshed. Did you manage to find a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to observe router event changes, when `routeChangeStart` ads had to be unmounted, when `routeChangeComplete` they had to be mounted remounted.

```
// components/Adsense.tsx

function Ads() {
  const adsRef = useRef<HTMLModElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const executeWindowAds = () => {
      try {
        // @ts-ignore
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
      } catch (error: any) {
        console.error('error ads======>', error.message);
      }
    };

    const insHasChildren = adsRef.current?.childNodes.length;
    if (!insHasChildren) {
      executeWindowAds();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
      <ins
        ref={adsRef}
        className="adsbygoogle"
        style={{ display: 'block' }}
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxx"
        data-ad-slot="xxx"
        data-ad-format="auto"
        data-full-width-responsive="true"
      ></ins>
  );
}

export default function Adsense() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [shouldMount, setShouldMount] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onRouteChangeStart = () => setShouldMount(false);
    const onRouteChangeComplete = () => setShouldMount(true);

    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', onRouteChangeStart);
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', onRouteChangeComplete);

    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', onRouteChangeStart);
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', onRouteChangeComplete);
    };
  }, [router.events]);

  return shouldMount ? <Ads /> : null;
}
```

On your layout page, for example a sidebar where each page has the same sidebar:

```
// components/LayoutBlogPost.tsx

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const Adsense = dynamic(() => import('./Adsense'), { ssr: false });

export default function LayoutBlogPost({children}: {children: any}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
      <Adsense />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try useRouter hook and handling router events inside useEffect:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Page() {
const router = useRouter();
useEffect(() => {
router.events.on('routeChangeError', handleChange)
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
}
```